# Replacing BT module with 433 MHz transreceiver module

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, rf, hc-05

I have made a prototype where I can send data from one arduino to another via Bluetooth(hc-05), they are working fine, but now I want to replace the BT module with RF module, how can I do that???

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use [VirtualWire](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/VirtualWire/) or [RadioHead](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/RadioHead/). You might need to "evolve" your protocol to handle message fragmentation and loss. RadioHead has support for that.

Cheers!

Comment: OK, I'm gonna try it.